# Java regex and .matches()

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to match a String with a regular expression in Java.

If I define the regular expression to match a digit like this:

```
private static final String NUMERIC_CHARS = "[0-9]";
```

The line below returns false where test = 12345678

```
test.matches(NUMERIC_CHARS);
```

I was expecting this to be true. According to oracle docs matches() returns "true if, and only if, the entire region sequence matches this matcher's pattern". Is this not the case here? 
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Your regex only for one digit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing anchor `+` (to match more than 1 digit), so use this regex:

```
"[0-9]+"
```

Your java code:

```
private static final String NUMERIC_CHARS = "[0-9]+";
```

Answer (score 1):

Your current regex only allows **1** digit. Modify it as follows:

```
private static final String NUMERIC_CHARS = "^[0-9]+$";
```

Then it will evaluate to `true`.